# Mysterious segfault though pointer is initialised

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am a newbie in C and I am trying to program a simple text editor, I have already written a 100 lines of stupid messy code, but it just worked. Until this SEGFAULT started showing up. I am going with the approach of switching terminal to canonical mode, and getting letter by letter from the user and do the necessary with each of 'em. The letters are added to a buffer, which is realloced extra 512 byte when the buffer is half filled, which I know is a stupid thing to do. But the cause of the SEGFAULT cant be determined. Help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

---

```
char* t_buf
int t_buf_len = 0;
int cur_buf_sz = 0;

void mem_mgr(char *buffer, unsigned long bytes){ //Function to allocate requested memory
    if(buffer == NULL){
        if((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bytes)) == NULL){
            printf("ERROR:Cannot get memory resources(ABORT)\n\r");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else{
        realloc(buffer, bytes);
    }
}

void getCharacter(){
    if(t_buf_len >= (cur_buf_sz/2))
        mem_mgr(t_buf, cur_buf_sz+=512);
    strcpy(t_buf, "Yay! It works!");
    printf("%s %d", t_buf, cur_buf_sz);
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is a local copy of `t_buf`. Changing `buffer` will not change `t_buf`.

Comment: Which line is your code crashing on?

Comment: Also note that `realloc(NULL, size);` is equivalent to `malloc(size);`, so no need to special-case for the first allocation. Thanks, standard library designers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things you need to understand first,

1. The `buffer` pointer is a local variable inside the `mem_mgr()` function, it points to the same memory `t_buf` points initially, but once you modify it, it's no longer related to `t_buf` in any way.

   So, when you return from `mem_mgr()` you lose the reference to the allocated memory and.

   To fix this, you can pass a poitner to the pointer, and alter the actual pointer by dereferencing it.
2. The `realloc()` function, behaves exactly like `malloc()` if the first argument is `NULL`, if you read the documentation you would know that.
3. Memory allocation functions MUST be checked to ensure they returned a valid legal pointer, that's why you need a temporary poitner to store the return value of `realloc()`, because if it returns `NULL`, meaning that there was no memory to fulfill the request, you would lose reference to the original block of memory and you can't free it anymore.

You need to pass a pointer to your pointer to `mem_mgr()`, like this

```
int
mem_mgr(char **buffer, unsigned long bytes)
{
    void *tmp = realloc(*buffer, bytes);
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        *buffer = tmp;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;   
}
```

And then, to allocate memory

```
void
getCharacter()
{
    if (t_buf_len >= (cur_buf_sz / 2)) {
        if (mem_mgr(&t_buf, cur_buf_sz += 512) != -1) {
            strcpy(t_buf, "Yay! It works!");
            printf("%s %d", t_buf, cur_buf_sz);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still SEGFAULTS, gcc message: Desktop/editor.c: In function ‘getCharacter’:
Desktop/editor.c:116:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘mem_mgr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   mem_mgr(t_buf, cur_buf_sz+=512);
           ^
Desktop/editor.c:102:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the & operator, still it prints garbage like 7f66eaced000-7f66eacf0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                      7f66ead04000-7f66ead07000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

Comment: You have errors somewhere else. In c, there is the concept of undefined behavior, you do something wrong somewhere and corrupted the memory, from there anything can happen, like what is happening now. Read a good book or tutorial on **Pointers** & **Dynamic Memory** for [tag:c].

Comment: Sorry for my lack of attention, i was in a hurry and totally forgot to dereference. It works, thanks for the detailed answer, now I better understand how pointers work!

Answer (score 1):

The call to

```
mem_mgr(t_buf, cur_buf_sz+=512);
```

cannot change the actual parameter `t_buf`. You will either have to return the buffer from `mem_mgr`

```
t_buf = mem_mgr(t_buf, cur_buf_sz+=512);
```

or pass a pointer to `t_buf`

```
mem_mgr(&t_buf, cur_buf_sz+=512);
```

Furthermore, a call to realloc may change the address of the memory buffer, so you will have to use

```
char *tmpbuf = realloc(buffer, bytes);
if (!tmpbuf)
    // Error handling
else
    buffer = tmpbuf;
```

`realloc(NULL, bytes);` will behave like a malloc, so you don't need a separate branch here. This makes in total:

```
char *mem_mgr(char *buffer, unsigned long bytes){ //Function to allocate requested memory
    char *tmpbuf = realloc(buffer, bytes);
    if (!tmpbuf) {
         // Error handling
    }
    return tmpbuf;
}
```

which somehow questions the reason of existence of the function `mem_mgr`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a good idea, this should be what i should have done in the code, but implementing it now may require touching lot of areas of my code.